# Wordpress .htaccess 301 redirect or Rewriterule for plugin path

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Very simple yet very confusing for me situation. I have a plugin on wordpress which generates dynamic results in a link as

```
www.mywebsite.com/testing/myname/1239812398123
```

I would like to use 301 to change this to:

```
www.mywebsite.com/myname/1239812398123
```

Please keep in mind that /1239812398123 will be dynamically generated therefore always different.

I already tried:

```
Redirect 301 /test/ /www.mywebsite.com/myname/
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/myname/$ /myname/? [L,R=301]
```

But nothing works :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your uri  pattern `^test/myname/$` matches when the uri is exactly `/test/myname/` it does't match `/test/myname/12389...` , Modify your rule like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/myname/([0-9]+)/?$ /myname/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found that dynamic part is letters and numbers so i modified the code:

> RewriteEngine On   RewriteRule ^testing/myname/([a-z0-9]+) /myname/$1
>   [L,R=301]

And it works but I also discovered that this will throw an error message from the plugin - this path doesnt exist.

Is it possible to change only the main section but IF there is dynamic part - dont do anything

so it the situation:

- if someone enter the main section `www.mywebsite.com/testing/myname/` rewrite will be `www.mywebsite.com/myname/`
- but if someone enter the dynamic section `www.mywebsite.com/testing/myname/123lkj123` rewrite will not be triggered therefore it will remain the same `www.mywebsite.com/testing/myname/123lkj123`

Thanks